# Неработающая прокрутка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, прокрутка, кроссбраузерность

Есть сайт

[image: screensubwindow]

В окне `.dropdownwindow` есть столбец `.windowmenuist`, для которого нужен скроллбар

```js
let cataloglistbutton=document.querySelector('.catalogbutton');
        let divmenuleft=document.querySelector('.CatalogMenuLeft');
        let divmenusearch=document.querySelector('.CatalogMenuSearch');
        let divmenuright=document.querySelector('.CatalogMenuRight');
        let divfreespace =document.querySelector('.CatalogFreeSpace');
        
        cataloglistbutton.onclick = function () {
            console.log('Before');
            if (document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display=="none")
            {
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.position="fixed";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginLeft="0";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginTop="0";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display="block";
                console.log(document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display);
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginRight="20%";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.width="80%";
                /*divfreespace.style.width="20%";
                divmenuleft.style.display="block";
                divmenuright.style.display="block";     divmenusearch.style.display="block";
                divfreespace.style.display="block";*/
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
                const simpleBar = new SimpleBar(document.querySelector('.windowmenulist'));
                /*simpleBar.style.visibility="visible";*/
                document.querySelector('.windowmenulist.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical').style.visibility="visible";
                document.querySelector('.windowmenulist.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical.simplebar-scrollbar').style.height="100%";
                document.querySelector('.windowmenulist.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical.simplebar-scrollbar').style.display="block";
                /*document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.position="absolute";*/
                /*document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginBottom="0px";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.paddingBottom="0px";*/              
            } else {
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display="none";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.position="fixed";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginLeft="0";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginTop="0";
                console.log(document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display);
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginRight="0";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.width="0";
                /*divfreespace.style.width="0";
                divfreespace.style.marginRight="100%";
                divmenuleft.style.display="none";
                divmenuright.style.display="none";      divmenusearch.style.display="none";
                divfreespace.style.display="none";*/                
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
                /*document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginBottom="0px";               
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.paddingBottom="0px";*/
            };          
                
            console.log('After');
        
        }
        
        let closebutton=document.querySelector('.close');
        /*closebutton.style.position="relative";*/
        closebutton.onclick = function () {
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display="none";
        }
```

```css
.contentdropdownwindow {
    display: flex;
    /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.CatalogMenuLeft {
    width: 25%;
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
}

.catalogheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}

/*.flexelem {
    flex: 1;
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}*/

.crossline, .bottompart {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 33%;*/
}

.windowheader {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: calc(100% - 2*37.5px);*/
    /*height: 34%;*/
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.windowheader h4 {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.flexdisabledscrollbar1, .flexdisabledscrollbar2, .flexdisabledscrollbar3 {
    flex: 0;
    width: 5px;
    border-right: 5px solid #f5f5f6;    
}

.flexline1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 33%;
}

.flexline2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 34%;
}

.flexline3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 33%;
}

.flexcontent {
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
}

.flexenabledscrollbar {
    flex: 0;
    width: 5px;
    border-right: 5px solid #f5f5f6;    
}

.windowmenulist {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}

.menulistitem {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

/* Works on Firefox */
.windowmenulist {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: blue orange;
}

/* Works on Chrome, Edge, and Safari */
.windowmenulist::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

.windowmenulist::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: orange;
}

.windowmenulist::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
/*
.simplebar-content-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}

.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical {
        background-color: #f5f5f6;
        width: 5px;
        visibility: visible;
}

.simplebar-scrollbar {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #e2e2e4;
}


.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical.simplebar-scrollbar {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.simplebar-scrollbar.simplebar-visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
*/

.close {
        margin-top: -14px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindow">
        <!-- <div class="crossline">
            <div class="close">&times;</div>
        </div> -->
        <div class="contentdropdownwindow">
            <div class="CatalogMenuLeft">
                    <div class="catalogheader">
                            <div class="flexline1">
                                    <div class="crossline">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar1">
                                    </div>
                            </div>      
                            <div class="flexline2">     
                                    <div class="windowheader">
                                        <h4>Каталог</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar2">
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flexline3">
                                    <div class="bottompart">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar3">
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                            
                        <div class="flexcontent">   
                            <div class="windowmenulist">
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Смартфоны и гаджеты
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Ноутбуки и компьютеры
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Телевизоры, аудио-видео, Hi-Fi
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Бытовая техника для дома и кухни
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Строительство и ремонт
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Дом и дача
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Фото, видео, системы безопасности
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Автотовары
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Канцтовары, Мебель и Офисная техника
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Красота и здоровье
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Спорт и отдых
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Товары для геймеров
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Уцененные товары
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Подарочные сертификаты
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Сервисы и услуги
                                    </div>                                  
                            </div>
                            <div class="flexenabledscrollbar">
                        
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="myscroll">
            
            </div>
            <div class="centerdropdownwindow">
                    <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--<div>-->        
<!--</div>-->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/currentversion.js"></script>
```

Подскажите как добавить полосу прокрутки к блоку `.windowmenulist`.

Comment: Зачем вы каждый раз ищите элемент `document.getElementById('dropdownwindow')`? Почему бы его не записать в переменную и использовать ее?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно windowmenulist задать фиксированную высоту. Например height: 200px;

```js
let cataloglistbutton=document.querySelector('.catalogbutton');
        let divmenuleft=document.querySelector('.CatalogMenuLeft');
        let divmenusearch=document.querySelector('.CatalogMenuSearch');
        let divmenuright=document.querySelector('.CatalogMenuRight');
        let divfreespace =document.querySelector('.CatalogFreeSpace');
        
        cataloglistbutton.onclick = function () {
            console.log('Before');
            if (document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display=="none")
            {
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.position="fixed";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginLeft="0";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginTop="0";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display="block";
                console.log(document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display);
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginRight="20%";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.width="80%";
                /*divfreespace.style.width="20%";
                divmenuleft.style.display="block";
                divmenuright.style.display="block";     divmenusearch.style.display="block";
                divfreespace.style.display="block";*/
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
                const simpleBar = new SimpleBar(document.querySelector('.windowmenulist'));
                /*simpleBar.style.visibility="visible";*/
                document.querySelector('.windowmenulist.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical').style.visibility="visible";
                document.querySelector('.windowmenulist.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical.simplebar-scrollbar').style.height="100%";
                document.querySelector('.windowmenulist.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical.simplebar-scrollbar').style.display="block";
                /*document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.position="absolute";*/
                /*document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginBottom="0px";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.paddingBottom="0px";*/              
            } else {
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display="none";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.position="fixed";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginLeft="0";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginTop="0";
                console.log(document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display);
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginRight="0";
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.width="0";
                /*divfreespace.style.width="0";
                divfreespace.style.marginRight="100%";
                divmenuleft.style.display="none";
                divmenuright.style.display="none";      divmenusearch.style.display="none";
                divfreespace.style.display="none";*/                
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
                /*document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginBottom="0px";               
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.paddingBottom="0px";*/
            };          
                
            console.log('After');
        
        }
        
        let closebutton=document.querySelector('.close');
        /*closebutton.style.position="relative";*/
        closebutton.onclick = function () {
                document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display="none";
        }
```

```css
.contentdropdownwindow {
    display: flex;
    /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.CatalogMenuLeft {
    width: 25%;
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
}

.catalogheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}

/*.flexelem {
    flex: 1;
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}*/

.crossline, .bottompart {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 33%;*/
}

.windowheader {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: calc(100% - 2*37.5px);*/
    /*height: 34%;*/
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.windowheader h4 {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.flexdisabledscrollbar1, .flexdisabledscrollbar2, .flexdisabledscrollbar3 {
    flex: 0;
    width: 5px;
    border-right: 5px solid #f5f5f6;    
}

.flexline1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 33%;
}

.flexline2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 34%;
}

.flexline3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 33%;
}

.flexcontent {
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
}

.flexenabledscrollbar {
    flex: 0;
    width: 5px;
    border-right: 5px solid #f5f5f6;    
}

.windowmenulist {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
}

.menulistitem {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

/* Works on Firefox */
.windowmenulist {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: blue orange;
}

/* Works on Chrome, Edge, and Safari */
.windowmenulist::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

.windowmenulist::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: orange;
}

.windowmenulist::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
/*
.simplebar-content-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}

.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical {
        background-color: #f5f5f6;
        width: 5px;
        visibility: visible;
}

.simplebar-scrollbar {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #e2e2e4;
}


.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical.simplebar-scrollbar {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.simplebar-scrollbar.simplebar-visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
*/

.close {
        margin-top: -14px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindow">
        <!-- <div class="crossline">
            <div class="close">&times;</div>
        </div> -->
        <div class="contentdropdownwindow">
            <div class="CatalogMenuLeft">
                    <div class="catalogheader">
                            <div class="flexline1">
                                    <div class="crossline">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar1">
                                    </div>
                            </div>      
                            <div class="flexline2">     
                                    <div class="windowheader">
                                        <h4>Каталог</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar2">
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flexline3">
                                    <div class="bottompart">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar3">
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                            
                        <div class="flexcontent">   
                            <div class="windowmenulist">
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Смартфоны и гаджеты
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Ноутбуки и компьютеры
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Телевизоры, аудио-видео, Hi-Fi
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Бытовая техника для дома и кухни
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Строительство и ремонт
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Дом и дача
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Фото, видео, системы безопасности
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Автотовары
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Канцтовары, Мебель и Офисная техника
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Красота и здоровье
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Спорт и отдых
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Товары для геймеров
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Уцененные товары
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Подарочные сертификаты
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="menulistitem">
                                        Сервисы и услуги
                                    </div>                                  
                            </div>
                            <div class="flexenabledscrollbar">
                        
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="myscroll">
            
            </div>
            <div class="centerdropdownwindow">
                    <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--<div>-->        
<!--</div>-->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/currentversion.js"></script>
```